# Show that there are exactly two homomorphisms $\alpha:C_6\rightarrow C_4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Show that there are exactly two homomorphisms $\alpha:C_6\rightarrow C_4$.

My first thought is to find the two homomorphisms, thus proving that there are at least two homomorphisms. Then I would need to prove that there are at most two.

I believe I have found one, that is $\alpha:x\mapsto x^3$. It works for a few elements in $C_6$. Though before I do all 36 possibilities and look for another homomorphism, is there a more efficient way to show that there are at least two? Also I am not sure where to begin showing that there is at most two.

Comment: $C_6$ is cyclic, so any homomorphism is determined by what the generator does. Map it to two different elements and check that the images are different, which shows there are at least two homomorphisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g$ be a generator of $C_6$.
Then $\alpha$ is completely determined by $h=\alpha(g)$.

Now $1=\alpha(1)=\alpha(g^6)=\alpha(g)^6=h^6$. Also, $h^4=1$.

So $h^d=1$, for $d=\gcd(4,6)=2$.

The question thus reduces to finding all elements of order at most $2$ in $C_4$. Each such element defines a homomorphism $C_6\to C_4$.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that there is a 1-1 correspondence between the normal subgroups of a group and the kernels of group homomorphisms. In other words, every normal subgroup of a group can be realized as the kernel of some homomorphism.

So for your problem, first examine the normal subgroups of $C_6$ (which is all of them since $C_6$ is abelian). This should give you some insight about the number of homomorphisms between $C_6$ and $C_4$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_6 = \{1,x,\ldots,x^5\}$ and let $C_4 = \{1,y,\ldots, y^3\}$. If $\alpha$ is a homomorphism, then $\alpha(x^k)=\alpha(x)^k$, so determining the value of $\alpha(x)$ completely determines how $\alpha$ acts on the other elements of $C_6$.

The other restriction we need to consider is that  $\alpha(x)$ must satisfy $1=\alpha(1)=\alpha(x^6)=\alpha(x)^6$. Which elements of $C_4$ satisfy this?